# Bootstrap Modal popup not showing on Index page

Tags: javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

Hi i have a ajax call wherebey when i click a loacation on a loaded map it shows my modal popup when a user is logged in,but when a user is not authorized/not logged into the app it's suppose to jump to the error: part in ajax and display a simple modal popup but it's not showing rather in dev tools "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 ()" and the pop up is not displayed,i tried redirecting to a random page on error: part and it successfully took me to the page but simple modal is failing to show,i tried all sources but nothing assisted,what i require is when a user clicks the location when they are not logged in to display a simple modal showing them a message that they first have to login.could you assist please,Thanks you.

here is my html

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="authorisationModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" id="authcontent">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                ...
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

here is my ajax call

```
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/GetOrchardLocation/" + id,
                success: function (res) {
                    console.log(res);
                    if (res != null) {
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "/Home/ShowWeatherPop?locationId=" + res.id + "&page=" + jumpDays,
                            success: function (res) {
                                $("#weatherPopupDiv").html(res);
                                showMap(regionName);
                            },//works fine until here


                           The problem is this part
                            error: $('#authorisationModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                                $('#authcontent').trigger('focus')

                            // this below works fine and redirects to the page for example
                             //window.location.replace("/Home/AccessDenied");
                            })
                        })
                    }
                }
            })

        } else {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "/Home/ShowWeatherPop?locationId=" + locationId + "&page=" + jumpDays,
                success: function (res) {
                    $("#weatherPopupDiv").html(res);
                    showMap(regionName);
                },
                error: $('#authorisationModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
                    $('#authcontent').trigger('focus')
                })
            })
        }
```

Comment: What is the version of bootstrap?

Comment: using  * Bootstrap v4.6.0 (https://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes.

First, you need to pass a `function(){}` in your `error` method.

Second, if you want to show a modal, you need to use `$("#authorisationModal").modal("show");` instead.

```js
const id = 1;
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/GetOrchardLocation/" + id,
  success: function (res) {
    console.log(res);
    if (res != null) {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/ShowWeatherPop?locationId=" + res.id + "&page=" + jumpDays,
        success: function (res) {
          $("#weatherPopupDiv").html(res);
          showMap(regionName);
        },
        error: function () {
          console.log("error1");
          $("#authorisationModal").modal("show");
        },
      });
    }
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log("error2");
    $("#authorisationModal").modal("show");
  },
});
```

```html
<link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div
      class="modal fade"
      id="authorisationModal"
      tabindex="-1"
      role="dialog"
      aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel"
      aria-hidden="true"
    >
      <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content" id="authcontent">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
            <button
              type="button"
              class="close"
              data-dismiss="modal"
              aria-label="Close"
            >
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">...</div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button
              type="button"
              class="btn btn-secondary"
              data-dismiss="modal"
            >
              Close
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you,i just forgot to place the <link
      rel="stylesheet"
      href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    />